# Plotting and handling date/time data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot

currently, I am working in a project and would like to plot data from a logger in a daily basis. The format of the written output is a .csv file and contains in a column the Date/Time stamp 
ex: 2018-10-15 10:00. In the other columns, there is just data in float format. I get the written stamp automatically in 10mins interval from 00:00 until 23:50.

I am looking to analyze the data and group it by days*using groupby() and further on compute mean and deviations of the day. I want to plot the mean and std_deviation data for several years as scatter or line graph. The major ticks are years or months with days as minor ticks.

On a daily basis I want to compare the variation of the mean within a certain month and plot against the entire time interval with hours as major ticks and every 10mins intervals as minor ticks. I want to be able to put this in a for loop if possible.

To be honest I've tried a lot of different possibilities but I can't achieve everything with only one. If I could, I would try not to use set_index() to be the Date/Time column, so it is easier to apply the group. I am using the Pandas module to achieve my whole analysis for convenience.

I would be really happy for any guidance.

Thanks you very much!!!!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be great if you could add some example code and perhaps paste a snippet of your dataframe into your question. It makes it much easier for us to work out a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of pointers:

When reading the csv with pd.read_csv (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you can specify which columns contain date/times:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
```

Then you can use `.dt` to access date/time specific features, see:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties

So you can add a column with only day numbers, like:

```
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.dayofyear
```

Then you can group by this new column..

Comment: Thanks a lot rje.  I want to plot data against the columns ['Time'] . For this its better to have the Time in time64[ns] format. I just found the to_timedelta() method and applied it the following way:

 `dffinal['Time']=pd.to_timedelta(dffinal['Date/time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),unit='s')´
Is there a more simple way to split the datetime stamp and having a ['Date'] having the format '%Y:%M:%d' and ['Time'] column? besides applying both code lines?
   `dffinal['Dates']=dffinal['Date/time'].dt.date´

best regards!